# How to stop table from resizing when contents grow?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a `table`, the cells of which are filled with pictures. I would like the pictures to grow larger when you hover over them and I would like the cells of the table to remain at the same size.

Changing the `img` style to `position:relative` doesn't work. Changing it to `position:absolute` does work, but I don't know the absolute position of the images.

Is there an elegant solution to this problem using CSS? I'd rather not use any JavaScript.

Comment: I'm using Firefox, and the images are not centered to the cell on hover. The top left corner of the image matches the top left corner of the cell. Which behavior are you looking for?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use `style="table-layout:fixed;"`, but this will make text or images overlap with other columns in case it exceed the width. Make sure not to place long text phrases without spaces.

Comment: using div inside the columns and setting overflow: auto; would tackle the concern mentioned, about overlapping. right?

Comment: To prevent the overlapping of column contents you can additionaly use text-overflow: ellipsis which provides in combination with overflow:hidden the non-overlapping cuttet content with dots... suffix notation:

.myTable{table-layout: fixed;}
.myTable td{text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow-x: hidden;}

Answer (score 14):

Use `table-layout: fixed` for your table and some fixed width for table itself and/or its cells.

Answer (score 11):

Use min-width in your cells, look an example here

```
.cell1{
display:table-cell;
width:100px;
min-width:100px;
border: 2px dashed #40f;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gueorguip13/avzuadhp/3/

Answer (score 4):

Set the table's `min-width` CSS property to the [`max-content` intrinsic value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-content), e.g:

```css
  table {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: max-content;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:top` to the td elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do to you can use position,z-index,left,top.

you should look at this way,

http://jsfiddle.net/wWTfs/

Comment: This works in jsfiddle, but in neither Firefox nor Chrome... WTH?

Comment: I tried in chrome and IE. It's works. But Firefox has be problem. You can use **#images tr td{display:inline-block;}** for FireFox. This is a bug. Drive from Firefox.

Comment: The image link on the fiddle is broken.

Answer (score 0):

use CSS transitions.

```css
.zoom {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
}
```

```html
<style>

</style>

<p>Hover over the div element.</p>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>
<div class="zoom"></div>
</td>
<td> test text</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

[w3Schools zoom hover](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp)