# How to make on a specific element scroll, rather than the entire page?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I've had issues before where specific controls would span over the width of the screen and create a horizontal scrollbar. Simply encasing the control in a `<div style="overflow:auto;">` would fix it so that just the contents of that div would scroll.

Here's what I get:
[image]

The entire page has a horizontal scrollbar, so if you scroll over to see all the grid's contents you can no longer see the search parameters in the table above it.

The table containing the grid in the screenshot is created as such:

```
<div id="divPageControls" style="padding-right:0px; padding-bottom:15px">

<!-- the table(s) for the 'top half' of the application -->

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="clsBorderColor" style="LEFT:10px; POSITION:relative; TOP:10px;">
    <tr>
        <td height="5px">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center">
        <div style="overflow:auto;width:100%;">
            <asp:datagrid id="dgAuditlog" runat="server" HeaderStyle-CssClass="clsGridHeaderText" ItemStyle-CssClass="clsGridCellText" PageSize="10" bodyHeight="220px" width="98%" CssClass="tblScroll">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-CssClass="clsGridHeaderText" ItemStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-Wrap="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
                </Columns>
            </asp:datagrid>
        </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="5px"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I've tried moving that `div` around to encase just the grid, just the `td`, `tr`, the entire `table`. That either doesn't make any difference, or gives me something perhaps even less usable:

[image]

The scrollbar clips the grid and now there's a vertical one too, instead of it "dropping down" to fill the page.

Anyone have any thoughts on what I can do to make just the block containing this table have the horizontal scrollbar, and also not "shrink" vertically?

**EDIT** Here's a screenshot of another grid, on a popup window, where only the grid scrolls:

[image]

In this case it scrolls vertically, not horizontally. But ultimately this grid in my actual question should behave the same; only that particular element should scroll, not the entire page.

Comment: Do you have tried overflow-x ?

Comment: That doesn't make a difference, unfortunately.

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for. You want just a horizontal scroll without a vertical scroll? You already got it, right. Why you need to change your DIV?

Comment: I want the scroll bar to be "contained" so that only the grid scrolls, not the entire page. The search parameters at the top should still be visible as the grid scrolls horizontally. @rkawano I editted my question with a new screenshot that shows a vertically scrolling grid for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

you have really messed up your question..but what I understand is you want a body part not to scroll and a scrolling div.If the div id is #divPageControls.

You can use css properties like:

```
       #divPageControls
        {
        overflow-x:auto;//If you want it to scroll Horizontally
        overflow-y:auto;//If you want it to scroll Vertically
        }
        body
        {
        overflow:hidden;
         } //Which will make body overflow hidden both horizontal and  vertical
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Using this, I don't get a scrollbar *anywhere*, I just get a grid that runs off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, editing again:

```
<table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; background-color: #00F; height: 100px">
        Grid here ...
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

See also here: [How to stop table from resizing when contents grow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523927/how-to-stop-table-from-resizing-when-contents-grow)

Comment: This gives me an "empty" scroll bar beneath the grid. I can see the buttons to pan left or right, but there is no *actual* scrollbar to track the position. Additionally, this still produces the scrollbar on the actual page as shown in my first screenshot.

Comment: Changed my code to overflow auto + overflow-y visible. See again.

Comment: If I put that around just the grid itself, inside of the `<TR><TD> grid </TD></TR>` then the grid just has a large margin on the left and right sides of it within the `<TD>`. Still a "main page" in its entirety has the whole scrollbar though.

Comment: This is pretty close now. I have to remove the `height` from the `div` because the user can change how many records per page are displayed. Unfortunately though this still shows a vertical scrollbar even though there is more than enough room for the grid to expand downwards. I think it's due to the `table-layout: fixed;` ? I tried setting `height:auto;` for the `table` but that results in similar behavior.

Comment: When a element grows inside a table, the table will resize, without regard CSS overflow definitions. It is a major behavior on browsers, see link I have posted. Setting table layout will block table resizing, and browser will use overflow defined on child elements. I believe you have to play with overflow-y (visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit) to solve your problem with vertical scrolling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89729/discussion-between-rkawano-and-sab669).