# How to create a table with 1 row and with different no of columns along with proper aligment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a table as shown below [image]

The table is created but the problem is when i enter some large data its structure is changing into irregular structure just as shown above.So my question is how to maintain the alignment of the table properly even though when i enter large data.

The code is used is as shown below

```css
#Invoicebanner {
  width: 610px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 0px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="Invoicebanner">
  <div style="border-left: 1px solid black;border-right: 1px solid black;border-top: 1px solid black;width:608px">
    <center><span style="font-size: 18px;"><b>Purchase Order</b></span>
    </center>
  </div>
  <table align="center" style="border: 1px solid " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr align="left">
      <td rowspan="5" style="border-right: 1px solid black;width: 300px;word-break: break-all;">
        <b>&nbspTo,</b>
        <br/>
        <!--  <%=request.getParameter("supplierName")%><br/> -->
        &nbsp
        <%=request.getParameter( "supplierAddress")%>
      </td>
      <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;border-bottom: 1px solid black;word-break: break-all;">
        &nbspP.O.NO
        <br/>
      </td>

      <td style="border-bottom:1px solid black;word-break: break-all;">
        &nbsp
        <%=request.getParameter( "poNo")%>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="left">
      <td style="border-bottom:1px solid black;border-right: 1px solid black;word-break: break-all;">
        &nbspDate
      </td>
      <td style="border-bottom:1px solid black;word-break: break-all">
        &nbsp
        <%=D ate%>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left">
      <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;word-break: break-all;">
        &nbspContact Name:
        <br/>
      </td>
      <td style="word-break: break-all;">
        &nbsp
        <%=request.getParameter( "contactName")%>
          <br/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left">
      <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;width: 110px;word-break: break-all;">
        &nbspContact No:
        <br/>
      </td>
      <td style="word-break: break-all;">
        &nbsp
        <%=request.getParameter( "contactNo")%>
          <br/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr align="left">
      <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;width: 110px;word-break: break-all;">
        &nbspEmail-Id:
      </td>
      <td>
        <td style="word-break: break-all;">
          &nbsp
          <%=request.getParameter( "email")%>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13075273/3680845

Comment: you can use table geneator online that may helps to generate precise  code

Comment: @jonystorm No effect on adding what you have given in the link

Comment: @chittioneterahertz there is an extra `<td>` in your code remove that you will be fine  <tr align="left">
      <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;width: 110px;word-break: break-all;">
        &nbspEmail-Id:
      </td>
      `<td>`
        <td style="word-break: break-all;">
          &nbsp
          <%=request.getParameter( "email")%>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

Comment: @chittioneterahertz check the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4zfxe8x4/

Comment: @RRR Its working well. Thank you for helping me

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra `<td>` tag  in your code (in last `<tr>`) remove that you will be fine... check the following fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4zfxe8x4/

**CODE**

```
<tr align="left">
      <td style="border-right: 1px solid black;width: 110px;word-break: break-all;">
        &nbspEmail-Id:
      </td>
      <td> <-- REMOVE THIS
        <td style="word-break: break-all;">
          &nbsp
          <%=request.getParameter( "email")%>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.container {
  width: 610px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.invoicebanner {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.table {
  width: 610px;
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
  height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.cell-1 {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="invoicebanner">Purchase Order</div>
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>To,
        <%=request.getParameter( "supplierAddress")%>
      </td>
      <td class="cell-1">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>P.O.NO
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Date:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Contact Name:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Contact No:</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Email-Id:</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahffhgfhgfhgghfhgffghg</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[working Codepen](http://codepen.io/venumadhavdiv/pen/wGWPyX?editors=1100)