# Vertical line between table rows. Merge two cells (headers)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, dreamweaver

I added a few simple tables in HTML. I am looking for a solution for two issues.

1) 
After I added this tables on my subpage I see that the tables are almost the same but they have in different place their horizontal line between table rows.

2) 
I would like to merge two headers.

I can't fix this using code-Live editor.

```css
div.blueTable {
  border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.divTable.blueTable .divTableCell,
.divTable.blueTable .divTableHead {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

.divTable.blueTable .divTableBody .divTableCell {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.divTable.blueTable .divTableRow:nth-child(even) {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.divTable.blueTable .divTableHeading {
  background: #5DBCD2;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #444444;
}

.divTable.blueTable .divTableHeading .divTableHead {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: left;
  border-left: 0px solid #F5F4F4;
}

.divTable.blueTable .divTableHeading .divTableHead:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.blueTable .tableFootStyle {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.blueTable .tableFootStyle .links {
  text-align: right;
}

.blueTable .tableFootStyle .links a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #1C6EA4;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.blueTable.outerTableFooter {
  border-top: none;
}

.blueTable.outerTableFooter .tableFootStyle {
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.divTable {
  display: table;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTableCell,
.divTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
}

.divTableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTableFoot {
  display: table-footer-group;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable blueTable" style="width: 100%">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableHead">People</div>
      <div class="divTableHead"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">Lang</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">54</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">Height</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">22</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">Weight</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">66</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">Et</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">55</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">Color</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">wb</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">A</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</br>
</br>


<div class="divTable blueTable" style="width: 100%">
  <div class="divTableHeading">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableHead">Country</div>
      <div class="divTableHead"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">E</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">11</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">P</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">23</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">R</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">32</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">H</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">45</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">I</div>
      <div class="divTableCell">57</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</br>
</br>
```

Comment: I've just made a quick [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zs9kbc4a/) using your code above. 
1) I'm not sure I understand what you mean about the horizontal lines, but I can see the vertical line between the 2 columns isn't in the same position, please confirm if this is what you meant.
2) What do you mean by merging two headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your first issue... I've had a good play around and if it is the vertical divider between the cells, then I believe it's a table resizing issue when characters are removed or added.

To prevent this, simply add `table-layout: fixed;` to the outermost container of the table, in your case it would be `.divTable`. With thanks to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13075273/2358222).

```
.divTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zs9kbc4a/4/) for the fix.

Check out this [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) to read up about the `table-layout` property.

In regards to your second issue, please explain in detail what you mean and wanting to achieve by editing/updating your question.

Lastly, I would highly recommend you read up on the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/), and implement it into your project if haven't already. It helps you to achieve the goals with ease. Bootstrap also has a [table structure](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/) too, which would be useful in your case.

Comment: Studocwho - your answer works fine, that was the first issue. 

A very great idea but I didn't know about this solution. Nice and easy.

.divTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

The second my issue is that I would like to merge cells fro row in a table: People because now there are two cells.  

The same issue is for the second table where I would like to merge cells for the row where is Country.
This is <div class="divTableHead">

Do you know now what I mean?

Comment: Would I be correct in saying you want to merge the 2 columns, for example the `Lang` cell with it's value cell `54`, throughout both tables, this would result in just having one column in each table with cells that would look like `Lang: 54`. Is this the correct understanding?

Comment: Not exactly. I would like to merge two cells (https://jsfiddle.net/zs9kbc4a/4/) in one cell. One cell is: People and the second is now Can't fly. 
I would like to merge these cells and should be one sentence: People Can't Fly , and it should be in the centre position.

Comment: Ah, so you want the header cells merging. I can't think of any way you could do it with your code. But if you are willing to change your whole html to use the html table tags, you can use the `colspan` attribute to set the header to 'merge' how ever many cells you need. But with this, you would have to have all the heading text in the one cell.

Here's some [documentation on the table layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) Incidently, the table demo on that page, uses the `colspan` attribute too.